# Call column index using numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to use groupby to begin analysis of a rather large data set, and my need for many calls requires I use a range method and use integers for column headers.

I am attempting to get a large portion of this data to inspect, and I am using np.arange for the fields.

I use the following style of dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1 : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                              'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                       2 : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                              'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                       3 : np.random.randn(8),
                       4 : np.random.randn(8)})
```

Using the following works:

```
names = np.arange(1,3)
x=df.groupby([1,2])
```

But I get the following error when I use:

```
names = np.arange(1,3)
x=df.groupby(names)
```

> Grouper and axis must be same length

It is unclear why one works, but the other doesn't, especially since calling simply `df[names]` yields what I expect.

I have an array that's 1474x480, which makes renaming the columns anything but the x-y coordinates far too difficult.

This is a simple x-y-z scan, which gives 3 values: Row Index = x, Column Index = y, and Value = z. The data is all numeric, np.float64.

My apologies if this is redundant, but I cannot find a similar case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
names = np.arange(1,3)
x=df.groupby(names.tolist())


print type([1, 2])
print type(np.arange(1,3))
print type(np.arange(1,3).tolist())

<type 'list'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: Brilliant. And I'm off…